# How can i add a tax rule if company exists?

Tags: rules, commerce

Hello fellow drupal developers, i'm creating a store on drupal commerce and one of the goals is to add VAT to the product if the buyer is a company.

I've added the company field on the address on both billing and shipping forms but how can i make the rules validate the field if its empty or filled? I've been hammering on this for a while and i could use some help!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "add VAT to the product if the buyer is a company." - are you sure you want it this way? I mean, usually you only need to care for VAT if selling to the consumers? Except that in some countries you must charge with VAT both companies and consumers, but are allowed to display Vat-excluded to companies.

Comment: Thank you for the replies Molot, well its the info i have at the moment, i have to do it like this, but i've been trying to get it done but still no luck. I'll read the link you gave me and try to explore the option you gave me as best as i can :)

Comment: @Badspeed Comment and flag for reopening if the other post doesn't work for this situation.